# HTML/CSS div structure

Tags: html, css, structure

I'm making a site for a client, designed by someone else. The site itself is relatively simple, but i can't seem to wrap my head around one specific thing. Please look at the following screenshot:

http://cl.ly/image/0M090g150S28

How would i make my html/css structure if i want those two green backgrounds (top & bottom) stay aligned with the content (which is 960px - margin 0 auto) when resizing, but also 'never-ending' when expanding the windows to, let's say, 3000px?

A never-ending background is easy.
A background fixed to the contact of a centered div is easy.

But the two combined? Please help me out here, i've been breaking my head over this for some time now. It's probably super simple..?!

Cheers!

Comment: can you explain it little more?

Comment: What don't you understand? The backgrounds (green colours, topleft & bottomright) should move with the centered containerdiv and not change position in relation to the elements that hover over them (like the logo, ...). BUT it must also stretch to the 100% width on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using two huge pseudo-elements on your content, set the backgrounds on those and use `overflow: hidden` on the body.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3387068)

HTML:

```
<section class="main"></section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .main { height: 100%; }
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
    width: 490px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(192, 186, 176, .7);
}
.main:before, .main:after {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}
.main:before {
    right: 60%;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 54%, teal 54%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.main:after {
    left: 60%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg, teal 46%, transparent 46%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've used CSS gradients, which won't work in IE9 and IE8, but you can simply use an image for those.

**EDIT**: I just had another idea - you could just use borders instead of gradients and in this way it works in IE9 and IE8. Just replace the CSS for the pseudo-elements:

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3387661)

```
.main:before, .main:after {
    border: solid 500px teal;
    border-width: 500px 750px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}
.main:before {
    right: 60%;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.main:after {
    left: 60%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This looks fabulous, great great job! I'll implement it in my own solution first, and then check this as the answer. Props!

Comment: I think the key was overflow: hidden on the body. I was already thinking in that direction, but couldn't figure out where and why the put it there. It works, very good solution! It's of course not pixelperfect because it's percentual, but it's as good as it gets! Cheers!

Comment: @ Ana: problem. Since you put overflow hidden on the body, my whole site can't be scrolled. I overlooked this.. Any way around this? :s

Comment: Does `overflow-x: hidden` (plus removing `html, body, .main { height: 100%; }`) help? I think it should, it works for me... http://dabblet.com/gist/3407822

Comment: I does not. Your demo though does work, but only with min-height. But when i use min-height, it doesn't work. I'd rather not work with min-height anyway. Please check the website @ http://www.mathijsdelva.be/puur (WIP)

Comment: It's because I used `:before` and `:after` which are like *children* of the container and you're using `#topbg` and `#bottombg` which are *siblings* of your `#container`. If you put `#topbg` & `#bottombg` inside `#container`, then it probably should work. And you don't need to use `min-height` if you have real content. I only used because I thought it was faster than copy paste dummy text...

Comment: Haha, brilliant! You saved me once again! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this though, but you might do something i once saw in yahoo stylesheets. 
Create an image for the top and the bottom. then define a css rule background image for the html tag for the top one with background positioning, also do the same for bottom image with the same background postioning this time attach it to the body tag. Hope it works

Comment: No this does not work. It's the same with the HTML tag as with other tags. If i add the background image to the HTML tag with a background-position left, it stays left and doesn't move with the content (so, the width of the window). If i position it centered, its position is in the perfect center of the window and moves with the content, but then it's not where the design says it should be (to the left).

Comment: ok what if we declare them as images with fixed positionin and z-index to make them be behind the content

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow, i gotta run, but thanks already a lot! I already tried fixed, but you gave me another idea! I'll keep you updated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://digitaldemo.net/stack-test.html

Here's the CSS:

```
htmo, body  { width:100% ;
height:100% ;
}

body    { background:#ececeb ;
margin:0 ;
padding:30px 0 ;
position:relative ;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif ;
font-size:16px ;
}

.top-left   { disply:block ;
width:395px ;
height:250px ;
background:url("top-left.png") no-repeat ;
position:absolute ;
top:0 ;
left:0 ;
z-index:-1 ;
}

.bottom-right { display:block ;
width:395px ;
height:250px ;
background:url("bottom-right.png") no-repeat ;
position:absolute ;
bottom:0 ;
right:0 ;
z-index:-1 ;
}

#container  { width:1000px ;
margin:auto ;
margin-bottom:20px !important ;
padding:20px ;
position:relative ;
top:0px ;
background:#ffffff ;
border:1px solid black ;
z-index:99999px ;
overflow:hidden ;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="container">

(your main layout and content go here)

</div>

<div class="top-left"></div> // this is the top left teal corner

<div class="bottom-right"></div> // this is the bottom right teal corner
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but no this doesn't help. You've accomplished to attach the background images to the body, but they do not move with the centered div! The idea is that the position of the logo and such never change in accordance to the underlaying background image!

Comment: Whoops - posted in the wrong place. I revised it. Have a look here: http://digitaldemo.net/stack-test.html.

Comment: It's still not the same as Ana's solution (look at here demo). But thanks for the trouble!